# JUnit5: Test multiple classes without repeating code

Tags: java, junit5

I have built my own implementation of a stack in Java, which looks something like this:

There is the interface "Stack" which provides the basic functions (pop, push, peek etc.). And then I have 2 concrete classes, one with the help of arrays and the one with a linked list (how is not important in this case).

Now my question: I want to test this with JUnit5 and because you can't instantiate an interface, I have to test each function once for the class with the arrays and once for the class with the linked list, so the code is unnecessarily long. Is there a way that I can test all functions for the interface or something similar? Because if now a third implementation was added, I'd have to rewrite it all again.

I have already tried 'ParameterizedTests', but I have not made any progress.

I would be happy about help!

Comment: [`@ParameterizedTest`](https://blog.codefx.org/libraries/junit-5-parameterized-tests/) should be the way to go - what problem do you have when you try it?

Comment: I do now know how to use it correctly. I just did not find any good tutorial for JUnit5.

Comment: Maybe post a minimal code example so that we can check where the problem is?

Comment: I think it would be enough if you could just give me some bit of code syntax which shows how I can use two classes with @ParameterizedTest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know what problem with `@ParameterizedTest` you are facing, but as you requested this is a very generic test example which could be useful for your test:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;  
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;
...

public static Stream<Arguments> provideStacks() {
  return Stream.of(
      Arguments.of(new ArrayStack()),
      Arguments.of(new LinkedStack())
  );
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("provideStacks")
public void test(Stack stack) {
  stack.push(1);
  assertEquals(1, stack.pop());
}

public interface Stack {
  void push(int i);
  int pop();
}

public static final class ArrayStack implements Stack {
  @Override
  public void push(int i) {
  }

  @Override
  public int pop() {
    return 1;
  }
}

public static final class LinkedStack implements Stack {
  @Override
  public void push(int i) {
  }

  @Override
  public int pop() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the code causes an error when I run it:
"java.lang.AbstractMethodError"

Comment: Err... Do you have the full stack trace please? Also, how do you run the test? I just ran it in Eclipse and it went well.

Comment: I updated my post and added the errors and I ran it in IntelliJ.

Comment: @Joey: I see, you might be running into a bug with IntelliJ - please check your version of JUnit and IntelliJ, [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/07/support-for-junit-5-in-intellij-idea-2017-2/) is an update for JUnit 5 M4 support in IntelliJ.

Comment: I updated JUnit und IntelliJ, now there is a different error. I updated my post and added the new error.

Comment: @Joey: ok - that's because it is running JUnit 4. Make sure IntelliJ uses JUnit 5 and you use the same import as those I added above.

Answer (score 5):

[Test Interfaces](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-interfaces-and-default-methods) would be another possibility. You'd define your tests as default methods of an interface and implement the interface once per Stack implementation. Each implementation can add additional tests etc.

```
interface StackContractTests {

    Stack newEmptyStack();

    @Test
    default void popsWhatWasLastPushed() {
        Stack stack = newEmptyStack();
        stack.push("foo");
        assertEquals("foo", stack.pop());
    }

    @Test
    default void cannotPopFromEmptyStack() {
        Stack stack = newEmptyStack();
        assertThrows(EmptyStackException.class, stack::pop);
    }
}

public class ArrayListBasedStackTests implements StackContractTests {
    @Override
    public Stack newEmptyStack() {
        return new ArrayListBasedStack();
    }
}

public class LinkedListBasedStackTests implements StackContractTests {
    @Override
    public Stack newEmptyStack() {
        return new LinkedListBasedStack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a private method which performs the test given the interface type as a parameter

```
private void testStack(Stack stack) {...}
```

Then call it in a unit test:

```
@Test
public void testImplementations() {
     testStack(new ListStack());
     testStack(new LinkedListStack());
}
```