# How to test different implementations for an interface in Junit5 without duplicating the code

Tags: java, junit4, junit5

May I ask how to write a junit 5 test for an interface with different implementations?

For example, I have a interface `Solution`, with different implementations like `SolutionI`, `SolutionII`, can I write only one test class to test both?

There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474695/junit5-test-multiple-classes-without-repeating-code) shows an example, but if there are multiple test method that needs to be called, I have to pass the parameter for every test method.

May I ask if there is an **elegant** way like what is used in the Junit4

In Junit4, I have a very elegant code sample as follows

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class SolutionTest {
  private Solution solution;

  public SolutionTest(Solution solution) {
    this.solution = solution;
  }

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> getParameters() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
        {new SolutionI()},
        {new SolutionII()}
    });
  }
  // normal test methods
  @Test
  public void testMethod1() {

  }
}
```

Junit 5 claims `ExtendWith()` is similar, I tried the following code

```
@ExtendWith(SolutionTest.SolutionProvider.class)
public class SolutionTest {
  private Solution solution;

  public SolutionTest(Solution solution) {
    System.out.println("Call constructor");
    this.solution = solution;
  }

  @Test
  public void testOnlineCase1() {
    assertEquals(19, solution.testMethod(10));
  }

  @Test
  public void testOnlineCase2() {
    assertEquals(118, solution.testMethod(100));
  }

  static class SolutionProvider implements ParameterResolver {
    private final Solution[] solutions = {
        new SolutionI(),
        new SolutionII()
    };
    private static int i = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
      return parameterContext.getParameter().getType() == Solution.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveParameter(ParameterContext parameterContext, ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws ParameterResolutionException {
      System.out.println(i);
      return solutions[i++];
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, `testMethod1` is using `SolutionI` and `testMethod2` is using `SolutionII`, which makes sense, I don't know if this helps to inspire a little bit.

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: So you are asking how to define parameterized tests in JUnit 5. Well, the JUnit 5 user guide has a whole chapter dedicated to parameterized tests: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not replying to this thread for a while. Comparing to the lotor's answer, I found some other ways I am currently adopting:

```java
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("solutionStream")
  void testCase(Solution solution) {
   // add your test
  }

  static Stream<Solution> solutionStream() {
    return Stream.of(
        new SolutionI(),
        new SolutionII()
    );
  }
```

The constructor needs parameters (Not type-safe)

```java
  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("solutionStream")
  void testOnlineCase(Class<Solution> solutionClass) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException,
      InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    Solution solution = solutionClass.getConstructor(Integer.TYPE).newInstance(2);
  }

  static Stream<Class> solutionStream() {
    return Stream.of(
        SolutionI.class
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 11):

Jupiter provides [Test interfaces](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-interfaces-and-default-methods) exactly for your purpose - to test **interface contract**.

For example, let's have an interface for string diagnostic contract and two implementations following the contract but exploiting different implementation ideas:

```java
public interface StringDiagnose {
    /**
     * Contract: a string is blank iff it consists of whitespace chars only
     * */
    boolean isTheStringBlank(String string);
}

public class DefaultDiagnose implements StringDiagnose {

    @Override
    public boolean isTheStringBlank(String string) {
        return string.trim().length() == 0;
    }
}

public class StreamBasedDiagnose implements StringDiagnose {

    @Override
    public boolean isTheStringBlank(String string) {
        return string.chars().allMatch(Character::isWhitespace);
    }
}
```

According to the recommended approach you are to create *test interface* that verifies the diagnostic *contract* in `default` methods and exposes implementation-dependent pieces to hooks:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertFalse;

public interface StringDiagnoseTest<T extends StringDiagnose> {

    T createDiagnose();

    @Test
    default void blankCheckFollowsContract(){
        assertTrue(createDiagnose().isTheStringBlank("\t\n "));
        assertFalse(createDiagnose().isTheStringBlank("\t\n !  \r\n"));
    }
}
```

and then implement this *test interface* for each solution specific:

```java
class DefaultDiagnoseTest implements StringDiagnoseTest<DefaultDiagnose> {

    @Override
    public DefaultDiagnose createDiagnose() {
        return new DefaultDiagnose();
    }
}

class StreamBasedDiagnoseTest implements StringDiagnoseTest<StreamBasedDiagnose> {

    @Override
    public StreamBasedDiagnose createDiagnose() {
        return new StreamBasedDiagnose();
    }
}
```

Use more hooks and not-`default` interface methods to test same-named solutions' aspects (like performance) and define new tests in the interface implementations for completely distinctive implementation pecularities.

Comment: Maybe it's my ambiguous description, I am not looking for a way to test a default method in an interface

Comment: @CheckwheiSin, this is very likely exactly what you are looking for. This is not testing `default` methods, instead these methods are the tests which should be performed. It can be translated to your use case: `StringDiagnose` -> `Solution`, `DefaultDiagnose` -> `SolutionI`, `StreamBasedDiagnose` -> `SolutionII`. Also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47486315/4288506) which might be easier to understand.

Comment: This is better than parameterised tests for testing different implementations of the same interface.  It's clearer that all tests are identical for each implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I tried *lotor* but for me it doesn't work from start and I found 2 ways to make it works.

jupiter : 5.9.2 (Jan 10, 2023) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api

1 - Declare *Implements Classes* inside *Test Interface*.
Code example:

```java
public interface StringDiagnoseTest<T extends StringDiagnose> {
    
    T createDiagnose();
    
    @Test
    default void blankCheckFollowsContract() {
        assertTrue(createDiagnose().isTheStringBlank("\t\n "));
        assertFalse(createDiagnose().isTheStringBlank("\t\n !  \r\n"));
    }
    
    class DefaultDiagnoseTest implements StringDiagnoseTest<DefaultDiagnose> {
    
        @Override
        public DefaultDiagnose createDiagnose() {
            return new DefaultDiagnose();
        }
    }

    class StreamBasedDiagnoseTest implements StringDiagnoseTest<StreamBasedDiagnose> {
    
        @Override
        public StreamBasedDiagnose createDiagnose() {
            return new StreamBasedDiagnose();
        }
    }
}
```

2 - If you use Intelligent IDEA, check the *build/run configuration*, it should looks like that:

For property "The type of resource to search for tests" select **pattern** and value:

```
my_test_package.StringDiagnoseTest$DefaultDiagnoseTest||
my_test_package.StringDiagnoseTest$StreamBasedDiagnoseTest
```

If you have problem, probably(by default) selected **class** and value `StringDiagnoseTest`.